# CORBA OmniOrb-4.2.1 : fails to compile on windows 8

Tags: c++, corba, omniorb

I am installing **omniOrb** on windows targetting to be used with VS 2012.

I followed all the steps from README.win32.txt  (omniORB-4.2.1).

However I am getting error while compilation. basically after **omnicpp.exe** is generated, make file doesn't move ahead mainly for **omniidl.exe** and other libs.

So for work around, i tried building individual sub-directories. However while in process it needs omniidl.exe which is missing.

Below is the error:

```
    make[1]: Entering directory `C:/omniORB-4.2.1/src/tool'
making export in src/tool/omniidl...
make[2]: Entering directory `C:/omniORB-4.2.1/src/tool/omniidl'
making export in src/tool/omniidl/cxx...
make[3]: Entering directory `C:/omniORB-4.2.1/src/tool/omniidl/cxx'
making export in src/tool/omniidl/cxx/cccp...
make[4]: Entering directory `C:/omniORB-4.2.1/src/tool/omniidl/cxx/cccp'
(dir="../../../../../bin/x86_win32"; files="omnicpp.exe"; for file in $files; do
 if [ ! -d $dir ]; then (umask 002; set -x; mkdir -p $dir); fi; dirs='. .'; case
 "$file" in /*) fullfile="$file";; *) fullfile=""; for _dir in $dirs; do if [ -f
 $_dir/$file ]; then if [ "$_dir" = "." ]; then fullfile="$file"; else fullfile=
"$_dir/$file"; fi; break; fi; done; if [ ! "$fullfile" ]; then echo "ERROR: Cann
ot find $file in $dirs"; exit 1; fi;; esac; base=`basename $file`; if [ -f $dir/
$base ] && cmp $fullfile $dir/$base >/dev/null; then echo "File $base hasn't cha
nged."; else (set -x; install -c  $fullfile $dir); fi; done; )
File omnicpp.exe hasn't changed.
make[4]: Leaving directory `C:/omniORB-4.2.1/src/tool/omniidl/cxx/cccp'
make[3]: Leaving directory `C:/omniORB-4.2.1/src/tool/omniidl/cxx'
make[2]: *** [export] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/omniORB-4.2.1/src/tool/omniidl'
make[1]: *** [export] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/omniORB-4.2.1/src/tool'
make: *** [export] Error 1
```

**Omnicpp.exe** was created already in previous run of "make export". However other exe and lib are not created and make exits like shown above.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Thanks.

Regards.

Comment: This should really be directed to the mailing list or support forum or whatever they provide.

Comment: Thanks. But I am wondering if anyone have come across same issue or is aware of  and was sorted.